# Mismatched Oracle drivers - need upgrade (10.2.0.1 to 10.2.0.5)

Tags: oracle

I was forwarded here by recommendation from Stack Overflow ......

We are running Oracle Enterprise software on various client and DB servers and we are experiencing a problem (outlined here) where the apparent mismatch between the oracle drivers are causing the errors.

Our db servers are using 10.2.0.4 and 10.2.0.5 drivers and the clients are using 10.2.0.1.

Firstly, are the drivers the same on the Express and Enterprise editions so that if I update a development server using Express version (I dont have the authority to upgrade the Enterprise version nor the time to commission that) and it is successful, can I reasonably expect an upgrade to the Enterprise client versions on other servers to be safe/error free, baring environmental factors of course ?

Secondly, can I upgrade to version 10.2.0.5 now or do I have to go to the 11g version only as a full upgrade obviously carries its own share of issues ?

Can I simply upgrade the driver from 10.2.0.1 to 10.2.0.5 on the client sides or is it advisable to upgrade the software too ?

I hope I have explained this correctly and that it is understandable as I have asked this on several Oracle forums with very little response.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the hyperlink - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3257800

Comment: It's not clear from your post here that the "drivers" are Oracle ODP.NET (not ODBC, JDBC, etc.).  Only the forums.oracle.com link mentions .NET in the ODP.NET forum.

Comment: They are the ODBC client drivers

Comment: The 10.2.0.X **clients** can be patched but I don't think they can be upgraded from say 10.2.0.4 to 10.2.0.5.  Also multiple clients can be installed side-by-side.  On WinXP, I've had 8.1.6 and 10.2.0.4 ODBC drivers installed on a single PC. Have you considered installing the [Instant client + ODBC supplement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)?  It takes up less disk space than the full Oracle client.

Comment: Can you add error messages, platforms and more configuration details? I assume Windows and multiple Oracle installations/versions on the machines which have the problems.